# Is there a more dynamic way to list numbered parameters in the "params.require" method in a Ruby on Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 application I have an object called "Game" (which tallies up the points that a player gets in a three-period hockey game), and three of the parameters are "period_1_goals", "period_2_goals" and "period_3_goals".

So when I declare them as strong parameters in the Games controller file, I get this:

```
 def game_params
   params.require(:game).permit(:player_id, :period_1_goals, period_2_goals, period_3_goals)
 end
```

Is there a faster way to define "period_X_goals" from 1 to 3, rather than listing each parameter individually?  You know, something using the same principle as this (which doesn't work):

```
 def game_params
   params.require(:game).permit(:player_id)
   (1..3).each do |x|
     params.require(:game).permit(:period_#{x}_goals)
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
def game_params
   params.require(:game).permit(:player_id, *((0..3).map { |x| "period_#{x}_goals".to_sym }))
end
```